# SQL Server : Date to hours comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report

I would like to retrieve items placed on orders for the last x hours. If the table stores this data as date, how would I be able to get the orders placed in the last x hours?

Comment: Can you present us with some of the dates you have in the DB? Is it a date or a datetime?

Comment: If using a `DATE` then you can't evaluate at an hour level.

Comment: @user2684009 . . . Either sgeddes's answer is correct (and you should accept it), or you should clarify the question pointing out why it doesn't work.

Comment: It does store data as datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateadd` for this assuming the field is being stored as a `datetime`:

```
select *
from orders
where datefield >= dateadd(hour,-1,getdate())
```

In the above example, I've used -1 for x.  Replace that for the last x hours.

Answer (score 0):

The answer sgeddes posted can work on query level. You can also filter the data for last x hours on report level. You just need to create a parameter(@Hours) in your report to specify what the "x" is. Then add a filter on your dataset.

Expression: =Fields!DateTime.Value

Operator: >=

Value: =DateAdd("h",-@Hours,Now())